# Using Office365-REST-Python-Client doesnt work on an external company's sharepoint

Tags: python

I've written a code in python using [Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client). It works perfectly well on myCompany's sharepoint site. But in another company's sharepoint site, I am getting auth token errors. I have owner priviledge in that sharepoint site. I was wondering if there is a sharepoint or maybe AD setting that disables the use of this API?

Comment: Have you granted app-only tenant permissions?  See:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs

Comment: @A.k.A.Fritz, no. I'm actually using username and password. It works fine on myCompany's sharepoint. I didnt have to do the app-only tenant permissions.

Comment: Can I assume then, that the other tenant doesn’t have multi-factor authentication enabled?  Are your credentials federated with their Azure AD or are you using credentials granted from their Azure AD tenant?